# mysql query using partition name vs where clause

Tags: mysql, partition, database-partitioning

I have a table partitioned by date.I noticed that when I query the table using the partition name it is faster as against querying using where clause.

Eg:

`select max(db_load_timestamp) from my_table partition(p20191008);` (executes in 9 seconds)

gives results faster than

`select max(db_load_timestamp) from my_table where date='2019-10-08';`(executes in 50 seconds)

Any idea why this happens as both the queries should take approximately equal time as both the queries leverage the use partitioning?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; sounds like something is amiss.

Comment: In particular, do you have `INDEX(db_load_timestamp)`?

Comment: @RickJames, no there's no index on db_load_timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a parition you are restrciting the amount of data that is accessed.  I found this quote:

> Partitioning allows tables, indexes, and index-organized tables to be subdivided into smaller pieces, therefore queries that access only a fraction of the data can run faster because there is fewer data to scan.

[At this link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-partition.php)

**Note** According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) partitioning is deprecated ...

Comment: No, partitioning is not deprecated.  What has gone away in 8.0 is where partitioning is handled.  It used to be handled in the SQL-layer and available to all Engines that handle it.  In 8.0 it is only in the InnoDB Engine.  Anyway, MyISAM is on its way to being removed.

Comment: @Rick James - thanks for the comment.  Partitioning is also in the NDB engine (according to the link I posted above, I haven't tried it.) For clarity the generic partitioning is deprecated, and as you pointed out not all storage engines will provide paritioning. At the link I posted above it clearly states: "As of MySQL 5.7.17, the generic partitioning handler in the MySQL server is deprecated, and is removed in MySQL 8.0, when the storage engine used for a given table is expected to provide its own (“native”) partitioning handler. Currently, only the InnoDB and NDB storage engines do this."

Comment: The not-so-obvious keyword is "handler".

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you use partitioning:

```
INDEX(db_load_timestamp)
```

will help

```
select max(db_load_timestamp) from my_table
```

And...

```
INDEX(date, db_load_timestamp)
```

will help

```
select max(db_load_timestamp) from my_table where date='2019-10-08';
```

In both of those cases, the result should come back so fast on a non-partitioned table that you won't even consider using partitioning.

Moral of this Answer:  Having the optimal index is usually more important than partitioning.